# Typo3: Add <style type="text/css"> to content

Tags: styles, typo3

Im currently working on some content within a typo3 page I only have editor rights on.
I'd like to add some styling to a table. To do so, I wanted to add the following:

```
<style type="text/css">

tr:nth-child(odd) {
background-color:#eee;
}

table {
border-spacing: 0px;
}

</style>
```

Typo3 seems to remove the tags when I save, rendering me unable to add the styles.
Is there a way to accomplish this in my situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you tried to add the styles in the RTE editor, but `style` or `script` tags will be removed on save, this is normal.

The main problem is, that you are not an admin. The only way to add some styles is adding a "Plain HTML" content element to the page and add your styles there, but it can be possible, that the admin deactivates that element for you.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help, this function is indeed (as expected) deactivated. But you've helped me clear out the situation. I now know what I have to ask the admin for.